# Javascript ASP.net set radio button enabled to false in modal pop up

Tags: javascript, asp.net

how can i set the radio button enabled to false as default when modal is show via click of button. It does not disabled the radio button when clicking the button. How do I do it correctly. Thank you

---

### my javascript function

```
function btnDefaultRadios() {

document.getElementById('<%= rdPermanent.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('<%= rdNonPermanent.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('<%= rdAdministrative.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('<%= rdTechnical.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('<%= rdWithhRata.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('<%= rdContractual.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('<%= rdCasual.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
        }
```

---

### my button the triggers the modal

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" SkinID="button" Text="Add New Position" Width="168px"  OnClientClick="btnDefaultRadios(this);"/>
```

---

### my modal - my controls were inside the panel

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Label1"
                PopupControlID="pnladd" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" OnOkScript="OkButtonClick()">
            </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Comment: Have you checked if there are any errors in the debug console on the browser? Perhaps add some console.log statements to see if it's reaching the function being called. depending on when the script is loaded up, it could be throwing a js exception.

Comment: Hello, the debugger does read my line but then, it is still not disabling. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a quick jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8Lq73hye/ shows that your javascript should work if it was executed. you could put a break point in the developer's tools on your browser and step through the code to see if the disable logic is indeed working.

What could be happening is that your js is executing, but then the button click is causing a postback straight after. if you are on your local machine, this could happen quickly without you knowing.

To prevent the unexpected post back, make sure your btnDefaultRadios function returns false

```
function btnDefaultRadios() {
    document.getElementById('<%= rdPermanent.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('<%= rdNonPermanent.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('<%= rdAdministrative.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('<%= rdTechnical.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('<%= rdWithhRata.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('<%= rdContractual.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('<%= rdCasual.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
    return false;
}
```

That the return false will stop the post back. A common mistake is also forgetting to return that function result on the OnClientClick call, so you must also change your OnClientClick to be

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" ...  OnClientClick="return btnDefaultRadios(this);"/>
```

EDIT:

A simplified working example of the aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test Client Side JS on Button Click</title>
    <script>
        function btnDefaultRadios()
        {
            document.getElementById('<%= rdPermanent.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('<%= rdNonPermanent.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
            return false;
        }

        function OkButtonClick(){}
    </script>
    <style>
        #pnladd
        {
            background-color: #fff;
        }
         .modalBackground
         {
             background-color: #666;
             background-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.75);
         }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="HtmlForm" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1">label1</asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Position" 
                Width="168px" OnClientClick="return btnDefaultRadios(this);" />
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnladd" Width="300" Height="300">
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rdPermanent" Text="Permanent"/>
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rdNonPermanent" Text="Non Permanent"/>
            </asp:Panel>
            <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnAdd"
                PopupControlID="pnladd" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" OnOkScript="OkButtonClick()">
            </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your code sir. but then, the modal does not popup

Comment: Your original question details above shows that the modal is hooked to a target control of "Label1" so changing the onclientclick behaviour of the add button shouldn't affect the showing of modal. did you mean to set the TargetControlID to use btnAdd instead of label1?